# What is the correct speed for serial communication?

Tags: stm32, serial, st-link

I am working with an STM32, more specifically a Nucleo-L476RG development board. I used the I2C ports to build a small virtual com port to broadcast some messages back to my computer.

The code on the MCU is working properly and I can see the final output in my serial monitor (coolTerm.)

During the connection setup, I had to specify the baudrate for the serial connection.  I set the value by trial - various values until the output was readable.  How can I calculate this value?

Here is a "hello world" example of code being transmitted:

```
strcpy((char*)buf, "Hello!\r\n");
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*)buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
HAL_Delay(500);
```

Comment: You can't calculate it, you just have to set it to the same speed for both ends of the link. If you don't control the speed of both ends, the one you don't control will have it stated somewhere in its datasheet or manual.

Comment: You look at the "code on the MCU" and determine what baud rate it is trying to generate.

Comment: I added some example code - the serial baudrate is set to 115200 - I am using the STM32 HAL - is this something I can see in the HAL UI ?

Comment: If you used the STM32CubeIDE code generator your can just enter the requested baud rate and it will generate uart setup code for you.

Comment: The same pin can be used for the I2C device (temperature sensor in my case) - I agree it should not be tagged I2C - I will remove the tag.

Comment: What kind of answer you want for this? The correct speed is what you want it to be, and it must be such that both devices can achieve it within some specified tolerance. The STM32 must initialize the UART to use this speed, same way than a PC terminal program would set the speed after opening the COM port for communications.

Comment: Is there a way to know the speed in advance. I did try several speed until I found the one that works. I was wondering if there is a deterministic approach. Thanks